# Is $\int_0^\infty\frac{|\cos(x)|}{x+1} dx$ divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Is it true that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{|\cos(x)|}{x+1} dx$$ diverges?

Any proofs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can use the fact that $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} |\cos x| \,\mathrm{d}x = 2$.

This implies that $\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{|\cos x| \,\mathrm{d}x}{x+1} \ge \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{|\cos x| \,\mathrm{d}x}{(n+2)\pi} = \frac{2}{(n+2)\pi}$.

Hence
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\cos x| \,\mathrm{d}x}{x+1} \ge \frac1\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k+2}=\infty.$$